# ros2 launch - how to send a ROS msg type as parameter

Tags: ros, ros2, parameter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am working on [a ROS msgs recorder](https://docs.ros.org/en/galactic/Tutorials/Ros2bag/Recording-A-Bag-From-Your-Own-Node-Python.html) and I am not sure how should I set up a launch parameter with given ROS message type.

I tried with something like:

```
self.declare_parameter(
    "msg_type", None, descriptor=ParameterDescriptor(dynamic_typing=True)
)
self.declare_parameter(
    "source_topic", None, descriptor=ParameterDescriptor(dynamic_typing=True)
)
```

and

```
start_string_recorder = Node(
        package="bag_recorder",
        executable="string_msg_recorder",
        name="string_msg_recorder",
        namespace=namespace,
        output="screen",
        parameters=[
            {
                "msg_type": "String",
                "source_topic": "/chatter",
            }
        ],
    )
```

But the resulting rosbag2 is empty and there is a problem with `ros2 topic echo /chatter` too:

`Cannot echo topic '/chatter', as it contains more than one type: [rcl_interfaces/msg/ParameterValue, std_msgs/msg/String]`

What is the best approach to launcher with this kind of needs (e.g. one of the parameters should be arguments is a ROS message type)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/398090/ros2-launch---how-to-send-a-ros-msg-type-as-parameter/) by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3064 on 2022-03-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I revised my code to use message type and a source topic as arguments in `__init__` function.

It works in code but I still don't know if a launch script wouldn't be better.

I can use `rosbag2` CLI there, but it's more annoying with parameters in YAML file, e.g. I couldn't set up a default path to save a folder with rosbag2. If anybody knows how to do it, I would appreciate your help.

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0